# Jekyll unmet dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I have a Jekyll site which was running perfectly few days back. Today when I ran `jekyll serve` it has started throwing error.

`Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-sitemap or one of its dependencies installed.`

I have jekyll-sitemap installed

```
gem query | grep jekyll-sitemap
jekyll-sitemap (0.10.0)
```

If I remove jekyll-sitemap from `_config.yml` and run `jekyll serve` then it thrown an error for `kramdown` is not installed, which is also installed.

Searching around the net have solutions like they have multiple versions of `kramdown` or `jekyll` installed but I don't have any such issues.

Here is my `_config.yml`

```
# Site settings
title: Malabya Tewari
header-img: img/home-bg.jpg
email: imalabya@gmail.com
copyright_name: Malabya Tewari
description: "Drupal developer, Open source enthusiast, trainer, blogger from Bangalore."
keywords: "Malabya Tewari, malavya, Drupal, Drupal Developer"
baseurl: ""
url: "http://imalabya.github.io"
twitter_username: malabya88
drupal_username:  malavya
facebook_username:  malabya88
linkedin_username:  https://www.linkedin.com/in/malabyatewari

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
highlighter: rouge
permalink: pretty
paginate: 10
exclude: ["less","node_modules","Gruntfile.js","package.json","README.md"]

gems: [jekyll-paginate, jekyll-feed, jekyll-sitemap]
```

Any help will be appreciated as I am very new or Jekyll or ruby.

Comment: Do you use bundler (bundle exec ...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took your code at https://github.com/imalabya/imalabya.github.io

Edited Gemfile to :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem "jekyll"
gem "jekyll-sitemap"
gem "jekyll-paginate"
gem "jekyll-feed"
```

Ran a `bundle update`, and then a `bundle exec jekyll serve`.

Everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks David. Solved my problem :)